# MySql Error 1054 when inserting into table that has trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have created a trigger on a table, and when I try to insert data into it I get MySql error "Error Code: 1054 'unknown column license_key in field list'"

The INSERT I try to do is this:

```
INSERT INTO LOAD_MASTER(license_key, state, total_pageviews, total_visitors, max_visitors, max_pageviews, ip, secret, read_time, url)
    VALUES ("order55555hytgtrfderfredfredfredftyu8ikloi98nhygt6", "preparing", 400, 1000, 200, 400, "202,2,35,36", "Hemmeligheden", 120, "http://google.dk");
```

The Trigger I have created is supposed to check the TABLE LOAD_STATS for the presence of the IP entered in the LOAD_MASTER table, and then based on the results change a value in another table called LICENSE

My trigger is here:

```
    DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER ip_check AFTER INSERT ON LOAD_MASTER FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE MK varchar(50);
DECLARE MIP varchar(15);
DECLARE LID int(6);

    SET MK = license_key;
    SET MIP = ip;
    SET LID = (
        SELECT l.license_id 
        FROM license_keys k, license l 
        WHERE l.license_id = k.license_id 
        AND k.license_key = MK
        );

    IF (SELECT COUNT(DISTICT(master_ip)) FROM LOAD_STATS WHERE master_ip = MIP AND master_key = MK ) > 3 THEN
        UPDATE LICENSE 
        SET STATE = 0 
        WHERE license_id = LID;
    END IF;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Any help on why I get this error would be much appriciated.

-Dan

Comment: What is the table definition for `LOAD_MASTER`?

Comment: The LOAD_MASTER is created like this

CREATE TABLE LOAD_MASTER(
license_key varchar(50) UNIQUE,
state enum ("preparing", "start", "end"),
total_pageviews int(6),
total_visitors int(6),
max_visitors int(6),
max_pageviews int(6),
date timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp,
ip varchar(15),
read_time int(3),
url varchar(2000),
secret varchar(50),
FOREIGN KEY (license_key) REFERENCES LICENSE_KEYS(license_key)
);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these lines

```
SET MK = license_key;
SET MIP = ip;
```

you probably meant to address `NEW.license_key` and `NEW.ip` respectively.

IMHO you can make more succinct. Try this

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER ip_check 
AFTER INSERT ON load_master 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(DISTICT(master_ip)) 
          FROM load_stats 
         WHERE master_ip = NEW.ip 
           AND master_key = NEW.license_key ) > 3 THEN
        UPDATE license 
           SET state = 0 
         WHERE license_id = 
              (
                SELECT l.license_id 
                  FROM license_keys k JOIN license l 
                    ON l.license_id = k.license_id 
                   AND k.license_key = NEW.license_key
              ); -- make sure that this subquery returns only ONE record
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

*There is some room for improvement rewriting an `UPDATE` with JOIN instead of using a subquery*